# Duplicated "post-header" class in Blogger

Tags: xml, blogger

I'm in the middle of developing my custom theme. The thing is that I'm trying to include post labels above, and date timestamp below title. 
When I use `<b:include data=` method, each time it outputs div with `post-header` class which obviously is not the best solution (there are 2 of those in a single post header). I also tried the old method with `<data:post.timestamp />`, but it gave me the `Can't find substitution...` error.

I tried to read docs, but couldn't find any solution to this. I'd appreciate any ideas.

EDIT:
Right, so I've created separate includable and included it inside post:

```
<b:includable id="postTimestamp" var="post">
    <div class="post-timestamp">
        <data:post.timestamp/>
    </div>
</b:includable>
```

But now I have following error in browser console:

```
<!-- Can't find substitution for tag [post.timestamp] -->
```

EDIT 2:

Thanks @Rafv! Actually I've already managed to display labels in a way you instructed me to, but using:

```
<b:include data='{ items: ["timestamp"] }' name='headerBylineOverride'/>
```

leaves me with following HTML structure:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <div class="post-labels" />
    <h3 class="post-title" />
    <div class="post-header" />
    <div class="post-body-container" />
</div>
```

The `post-header` div is automatic, I want this to be manual with different class, like `post-timestamp`.

EDIT 3:

Turns out that ID `postTimestamp` is somehow reserved for standard Blogger include id. After removing the `includable` it works almost as intended - timestamp is being generated with following error some in between the elements:

```
<span class="byline post-timestamp">
    <!--Can't find substitution for tag [byline.label]-->
    <meta content="URL">
    <a class="timestamp-link" href="URL" />
</span>
```

Thanks,
Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

In some case, you can't use `<data:.../>` inside the tag. 
Try this  `data='{ items: [ "timestamp"] }'`. Your markup should be like this:

```
<b:include data='{ items: ["timestamp"] }' name='headerBylineOverride'/>
```

To make the label above your title, just make a custom post labels with new or different class and put it above title, or find (usually default blogger template title) `<div class='post-title-container'>` and put above it. Here's an example:

```
<div class='labels-post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
        <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> 
            <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a> 
            <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'/>
        </b:loop> 
     </b:if>
</div>
```

Then style it as well as you want:

```
.labels-post {
  //styling...
}

.labels-post a {
  //stuff...
}
```

And for date timestamps, just put `<b:include data='post' name='headerByline'/>` below `<div class='post-title-container'>` it could made your timestamp below your title.

Use `display:none` to the element or class that you want to hide if there's any duplicate of it

**Edit**:

```
<div class="post-labels" />
<h3 class="post-title" />
<div class="post-header" />
<div class="post-body-container" />
```

is not a tag, see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn),
and last you can read [page element tag](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46888?hl=en&ref_topic=6321969) so does [widget tag layout](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995) by google-blogger doc for further information

Comment: I get it all, I'm aware of how the HTML looks like :) This is final output in browser, after XML template is compiled. Blogger tag automatically creates div with "post-header" class, which is the main problem here.